# Kubernetes: "kubeadm init" is hanging

Tags: kubernetes

Whenever I run:

```
# systemctl start docker
# kubeadm reset
# kubeadm init
```

it always hangs at the end:

```
[etcd] Wrote Static Pod manifest for a local etcd instance to "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/etcd.yaml"
[init] Waiting for the kubelet to boot up the control plane as Static Pods from directory "/etc/kubernetes/manifests".
[init] This might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled.
```

Even tried wiping out, reinstalling, etc. but no difference.

I'd appreciate your help in advance!

Thank you.

Comment: look at the /var/log/message file for more details. something wrong with server configuration, kublet process is not starting.

Comment: Check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/50288221/1163667. This is how I solved it. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As @sfgroups mentioned, this clearly seems to be an issue with `kubelet`. For some reason it is not starting, so I advise you to run this command

```
 sudo journalctl -u kubelet
```

This will provide more info about the issue. I would also check if it is an issue with docker itself. I would try to launch a container and see if it works

```
  docker run -ti bitnami/mongodb
```

I have seen some issue with some kernel updates and docker, so if it fails, then you know that the reason is docker.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that crio was missing a package, no idea why

run `journalctl -xeu crio`

If you find something such as : `crio[5548]: /usr/libexec/crio/conmon: error while loading shared libraries: libglib-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

If you are using debian you can get the package running:

`apt-get install libglib2.0-0`

then restart crio : `sudo systemctl restart crio`

`kubeadm reset`

`kubeadm init`

Otherwise check that you are using systemd or cgroupfs accordingly.