# Kubeadm init stops at image pulling

Tags: kubernetes, init, kubeadm

I'm having some troubles with initializing the master using `kubeadm`..

I'm trying to follow https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/ . I installed `docker`, `kubelet`, `kubeadm` and `kubectl`.

Now I executed `kubeadm init`, but it stops at `[init] This might take a minute or longer if the control plane images have to be pulled.`

I looked into `journalctl` and there I found out that: `Unable to update cni config: No networks found in /etc/cni/net.d` and  `Failed to list *v1.Pod: Get https://10.159.43.30:6443/api/v1/pods?fieldSelector=spec.nodeName%3Deskubernv01&limit=500&resourceVersion=0: dial tcp 10.159.43.30:6443: getsockopt: connection refused`.

I tried to set up weave-net with `kubectl apply -f https://git.io/weave-kube` but it cannot connect: `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`.

I cannot copy `admin.conf` file which should allow me to connect from `/etc/kubernates`, because `kubeadm init` failed so these are not proper files.

I feel like I'm in a loop here and I'm mising something.

I'm out of options right now. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way out.

If anyone has a problem like this - check docker logs.

In my case it was proxy which was unset for docker service.
To set it I used:

1. Create a systemd drop-in directory for the docker service:

   `$ sudo mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d`
2. Create a file called /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/http-proxy.conf that adds the HTTP_PROXY environment variable:

   `[Service]
   Environment="HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.example.com:80/"`

Source: https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/#httphttps-proxy

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by specifying the version [1.9.7-00] when installing kubeadm,kubectl,and kubelet , like this:

```
# ----- Install kubernetes -----
# kubeadm docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/install-kubeadm/
echo " "
echo - Installing Kubernetes...
apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add -
cat <<EOF >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
deb http://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main
EOF
apt-get update
apt-get install -y kubelet=1.9.7-00 kubeadm=1.9.7-00 kubectl=1.9.7-00
```

Note the **kubelet=1.9.7-00 kubeadm=1.9.7-00 kubectl=1.9.7-00**